# First Unique Character

Tags: python

Given a string, find the first non-repeating character in it and return its index. If it doesn't exist, return -1. Input string already all lowercase.

Why does my code not work?

```
str1 = input("give me a string: ")

def unique(x):
    stack = []

    if x is None:
        return (-1)

    i = 0
    while i < len(x):
        stack = stack.append(x[i])
        if x[i] in stack:
            return(i)
        else:
            i += 1

unique(str1)
```

Comment: change `stack = stack.append(x[i])` to `stack.append(x[i])`. 
`stack.append()` does not return anything, so when you put that into a variable, the variable will contain None.

Comment: Additionally, `x[i] in stack` is always going to be true after you just added it to `stack`.

Answer (score 1):

```
str1 = input("give me a string: ")

def unique(x):
    for i in x:
        if x.count(i) == 1:
            return x.index(i)
    else:
        return -1

print(unique(str1))
```

This will work

**Explanation**

Instead of using the list `stack` use the `count()` function of the string. The function `unique(x)` will return the index of that first element whose count is 1 in the `str1` string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know what your code is doing to figure out why it doesn't work, let's breakthrough it step by step.

1. you create a empty list `stack` for later use, that's fine.
2. `if x is None` is a strange way to check if a string is given, and it doesn't work because even a empty string `""` is not equal to `None`. `is` is used to check if both sides are the same object, and `==` is a better operator to check if values of both sides are the same. Therefore, `if x == ""` is better, but `if not x` is even better to check if something is empty.
3. using variable `i` and while loop to iterate the string is fine.
4. `append()` change the list in-place and return `None`, so `stack = stack.append(x[i])` is assigning `None` to stack.
5. `in stack` is going to raise `TypeError` as `NoneType` is not iterable. If we change the last line to `stack.append(x[i])`, it now works, as `x[0]` is already appended to `stack`, if `x[0]` in `stack` must be `True` and return `0` for your result.

That's what your code is doing, you just append the first character and return the first index. You need to go through the whole string to know if a character is unique.

Although Rishabh's answer is cleaner, I provide a way to doing it using lists to save seen and repeated characters, then read the string again to find the index of unique character.

```
x = input("give me a string: ")
def unique(x):
    seen = []
    repeated = []
    for char in x:
        if char in seen:
            repeated.append(char)
        else:
            seen.append(char)
    for idx, char in enumerate(x):
        if char not in repeated:
            return idx
    return -1

print(unique(x))
```